# Urllib browerify: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node-modules, urllib, browserify

I want to use `urllib` in javascript project (precisely for chrome extension). I need to use some node modules and that includes also `urllib`. I found out that by using `browserify`, it is possible to do so. But I got this error after creating the bundle file for urllib.
Here is how i tried to include `urllib` in my project:

1. `npm install urllib --save`
2. `browserify -r urllib -o bundle.js`

Here is the error I received in `bundle.js` file:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
var NODE_MAJOR_VERSION = parseInt(process.versions.node.split('.')[0]);
```

Does anyone know whether it is because `urllib` is not compatible with `browserify` or have I overlooked any step?

Comment: I have the same error but using the "got" module: const nodejsMajorVersion = Number(process.versions.node.split('.')[0]);